# recurrence relation with non constant coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve a second order differential equation and I got a recurrence. Can someone help to solve $$n(n-1+q)a_{n}-a_{n-3}+e\cdot a_{n-2}=0$$ where $q$, $e$, and $a_{0}$ are some real numbers with $a_{1}=0$ and $a_{2}=-e\cdot a_{0}/(2(1+q))$.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question so that it looks a little cleaner. Some $a_0$'s just floating in there

Comment: Recurrences like this don't always have neat solutions. One approach is to calculate the next few terms to see whether there is a pattern.

Comment: I actually calculate the first six terms, the dependence on n and q clears up but it remains unclear in "e"

Comment: Maybe if you edit into your question what you have found out about $n$ and $q$, someone will be able to help you with $e$.

Comment: I'm very hapy becouse I found a solution in "Combinatorics Function technics" hfa1.physics.msstate.edu/064.pdf

Comment: This recurrence relation comes from what second order differential equation?

Comment: I know that this recurrence relation comes from solving the ODE $xy''+qy'+x(e-x)y=0$ by power series method. Am I guessing right?

Comment: Usually, what you get out of such an exercise is the differential equation you started with...